# XMLHttpRequest is working correctly when made a cross-origin request, but Fetch does not initiate original request and sends only options request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a GET/POST request with fetch but and it sends only OPTIONS request and does not intitiate the 
real request. But when i tried same request using XMLHttpRequest it works(it sends OPTIONS and GET/real request).
Also server sends the correct headers for both request. Please suggest why the request is not working 
with fetch API. Below is the code.

Fetch did not give any console error about cross-origin. It just did not initiate the real request after the OPTIONS 
request is successfully completed.

Below is the code that i am using for request with XMLHttpRequest and fetch.

```js
//XMLHttpRequest(this works perfectly, sends OPTIONS and real request)

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", API+'controller/function', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-custom-header", "app");
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

```js
// Fetch preflight request (this sends only OPTIONS request)
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("x-custom-header", "app");
fetch(API+'controller/function', {
    headers: myHeaders
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

here is my server response header:

```html
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, Authorization,Cache-Control, x-custom-header, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:21
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I also set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000", but still not working with fetch.

Comment: `this sends only OPTIONS request` - sure, and what's the response? what's in the console as far as errors go? have you tried setting mode: cors in the fetch request?

Comment: I am getting the response ({"success":true})  from server successfully for OPTIONS request.

yes i tried setting mode:cors in fetch request, but still not working

Comment: it's odd that only the OPTIONS request is sent, and you get no feedback whatsoever in either the browser console or network tab as to why the OPTIONS failed - perhaps you're filtering in the console/network tab? Which browser? Have you tried a better browser?

Comment: those response headers in your question, are they the OPTIONS response headers? seems odd to have `Content-Length:21` in OPTIONS response headers. What http status does OPTIONS return?

Comment: Yes, it's odd, I am using the chrome Version 62.0.3202.62. I am filtering on network tab with xhr filter, there is only one OPTIONS request with 200 status and server response.

Comment: yes they are the OPTIONS response headers

Comment: have you tried a different browser? wouldn't surprise me if Chrome 62 is broken (there's been interesting bugs in it!!)

Comment: Yes i tried firefox as well, but didn't get any luck

Comment: Yeah that doesn’t look like a successful OPTIONS response. The `Content-Length:21` and `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` seem to indicate that the server may have actually sent back an HTML-formatted error page. Regardless, you probably want to actually look at what the content (response body) is — and then update the question to include that info.